# React <a> tag issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Thanks for reading this. I am starting to learn React and in an exercise I am following, the goal is create a component that renders an URL an goes to it. My component stands like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>URL:</p>
    <p><a href="{props.url}" target="_blank">{props.url}</a></p>
  </div>
);
```

For a test, I render my component like this:

```
<Url
  url="https://www.google.com/"
/>
```

I am working using Webpack dev-server. The problem is when I click the link. I don't know why it takes me to http://localhost:8080/%7Bprops.url%7D instead of google page. What is wrong my code? How should I do it the right way? The example does not explain anything about this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Try rendering `href={props.url}` without the `"` double quote characters:

```
export default (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>URL:</p>
    <p>
      <a href={props.url} target="_blank">{props.url}</a>
    </p>
  </div>
);
```

That way it will not encode the quote characters, but rather render the `props.href` string value.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark the answer that helped you achieve the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to remove the quotes for the href

```
export default (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>URL:</p>
    <p><a href={props.url} target="_blank">{props.url}</a></p>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: @alexanderStaroselsky's answer above is correct. I was just a few seconds too slow :)

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe the error was because of the quotes... I guess I never will be surprised again...

Comment: No problem :) Don't forget to accept the above answer so @alexanderStaroselsky can be awarded reputation for the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should try and do a callback function onClick of your P tag like so:

```
<p onClick={this.goToUrl} />

goToUrl() {
  window.location.assign('https://www.google.com/')
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer